# Proof by induction (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, induction

*This is my first question on here so please bear with me, thank you.*

> Prove that for all positive integers $n$
>   $$2(1+2+...+n)^4 = (1^5 + 2^5 +...+ n^5) + (1^7 + 2^7 +...+ n^7)$$

After establishing the base case, I proceeded to the induction:

$2(1+2+...+(n+1))^4 = (1^5 + 2^5 +...+ (n+1)^5) + (1^7 + 2^7 +...+ (n+1)^7)$

$2(1+2+...+(n+1))^4 = (1^5 + 2^5 +...+ n^5)+(n+1)^5 + (1^7 + 2^7 +...+n^7)+(n+1)^7$

$2(1+2+...+(n+1))^4 = 2(1+2+...+n)^4 + (n+1)^5 + (n+1)^7$

$2(1+2+...+(n+1))^4 - 2(1+2+...+n)^4 = (n+1)^5 + (n+1)^7$

$2[(1+2+...+(n+1))^4 - (1+2+...+n)^4] = (n+1)^5 + (n+1)^7$

And from here I've hit a wall and can't figure out how to continue. I tried substituting $(1+...+n) = [n(n+1)]/2$ and $(n+1)=[2(1+...+n)]/n$ but to no avail.

Comment: It seems like you are starting by assuming what you wish to prove.  You want to assume $(1 + .... +n)^4 = (1 + 2+....+n)^5 + (1+2+...+n)^7$ and prove that that mean  $(1 + .... +n+(n+1))^4 = (1 + 2+....+n+(n+1))^5 + (1+2+...+n+(n+1))^7$.  You assumed it off the bat which makes me wonder what you are going to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$1+2+\cdots+n =\frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$ and $$1+2+\cdots+n+1 =\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}.$$
Therefore, the left-hand side of the last equation is
$$\frac{(n+1)^4}{8}\left((n+2)^4 -n^4\right)=\frac{(n+1)^4}{8}\left((n+1+1)^4 -(n+1-1)^4\right).$$
But $$(a+1)^4-(a-1)^4 = ((a+1)^2)^2-((a-1)^2)^2\\=((a+1)^2-(a-1)^2)((a+1)^2+(a-1)^2) \\=(a+1+a-1)(a+1-a+1)(a^2+1+2a+a^2+1-2a)\\=8a(a^2+1).$$
Using the above relationship for $a=n+1$, $$\frac{(n+1)^4}{8}\left((n+2)^4 -n^4\right)=(n+1)^4(n+1)((n+1)^2+1) = (n+1)^5+(n+1)^7.$$

Comment: Beautiful solution and a short cut.

Comment: Why is it (a+1+a-1)(a+1-a+1)? How did you do that?

Comment: @A.Mercs I have used $x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$ to factorize $(a+1)^2-(a-1)^2$.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You must prove $$2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i\right)^4 = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i^5 + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i^7.$$

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

You have $$2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i\right)^4 = 2\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\right)^4 + 4(n+1)S_n^3 + 6(n+1)^2S_N^2 + 4(n+1)^3S_n + (n+1)^4 \right).$$